# VBA Macro - Trying to write code that will dynamic filter excel sheet and then copy values in a certain column

Tags: excel, vba

VBA Macro - Trying to write code that will dynamic filter excel sheet and then copy values with that filter applied in a certain column

The scenario:
There are two excel sheets: the original document and a newly created excel document that the data will be exported to.

I have already tried recording a macro to filter the original document and then copying/pasting that code into the macro I am creating (called "KPI_DATA"). The copy/pasted code will not work in KPI_DATA but it works fine in the separate, recorded macro (called "Macro1").

What is happening?

Additionally, in KPI_DATA I am attempting to set the range to all cells with entries in them so that the macro KPI_DATA can be applied to other excel documents as well. For this, I am trying to use the code "ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criterial:="2"" [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZF4k.png)

Can anyone advise?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mMtk.png)

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$4:$DB$2168").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="2"
End Sub

Sub KPI_Data()

    
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Dim BOM As Workbook
'
    'Adding New Workbook
   Set wkb = Workbooks.Add
  ' variable for the bom workbook
    Set BOM = ThisWorkbook
  
 ' Dynamic filter BOM sheet
 ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criterial:="2"

....etc
End Sub
```

Comment: Please add the code as text, not as image.

Comment: @FunThomas updated